# Nested datatype in input variable of Hasura Action

Tags: graphql, hasura, nested-types

I am trying to create a Hasura Action that takes an input with a nested type. I [researched](https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/4796) on this topic and according to Hasuras GitHub nested types are now a [supported feature of Hasura](https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/commit/40678855d03c70204419b7b27fa9068897cc4c7c). Anyways, when trying to create my action I get the error: "code": "invalid-configuration", "error": "Inconsistent object: in action "create_organisation"; the type: "Contact" is not defined in custom types or it is not a scalar/enum/input_object"
[image]
My action config is attached here. Contact is defined and all its members are just plain strings. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of hasura?

Comment: The version is 2.20.1

Answer (score 1):

For passing 'Contact' in input params you have to define it with 'input' keyword.
[image]

[image]

This is working.

Comment: I figured that by now, too. But thanks! Still: really counter-intuitive to define two costum types that do the same thing...